# New session id EveryTime

Tags: rest, session, angular5

I am using Angular 5 + spring REST.

I have created rest service, and keeping some data in session.

```
@RequestMapping(value ="/controls" , method= RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public List<InputBase> onLoadResponse(@RequestParam (value = "userId") String inputParam ,HttpServletRequest httpServletReques,HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, HttpSession session){
    super.responseHeader(httpServletReques, httpServletResponse);
    session.setAttribute("root", "root");
    return controlService.getControl(inputParam, session);
}
```

Issue is that when I hit this request form Postman i get same session, but from angular if get different session for every request.

This new session is created by browser or angular ? and is it possible to keep same session for each request ?

Comment: Did you added 'proxy.conf.json' file for proxy details in your Angular Project?

Comment: yes , adding poxy.conf.json worked !! Thanks @RohanKadu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding proxy configuration resolved the issue. Here is the link : [Link](https://dzone.com/articles/configure-a-proxy-for-your-api-calls-with-angular)